# SQL Query , Group by Prints too many records

Tags: sql, vb.net, select

I have two following tables

```
Emp_ID   FirstName
------------------------------
1            John
2            Mark
3            Steve
```

table 2 : Emp_Transaction

```
Trans ID    Emp_ID    start_Date  End_date    Paid_status  Total_Hours     Total_Pay
---------------------------------------------------------
1               1     01/07/13    01/14/2013     True       15.00       75.00
2               1     01/15/13    01/21/2013     False      10.00       50.00
3               1     01/21/13    01/27/2013     False      10.00       50.00

4               2     01/07/13    01/14/2013     False      15.00       75.00
5               2     01/15/13    01/21/2013     False      10.00       50.00
6               2     01/21/13    01/27/2013     False      10.00       50.00

7               3     01/07/13    01/14/2013     True       15.00       75.00
8               3     01/15/13    01/21/2013     True       10.00       50.00
9               3     01/21/13    01/27/2013     False      10.00       50.00
```

Result should print like this ( oldest unpaid date)

```
ID  FirstName   start_Date  End_date    Paid_status  Total_Hours     Total_Pay
--------------------------------------------------------------
1             John      01/15/13    01/21/2013   False      10.00       50.00            
2             Mark      01/07/13    01/14/2013   False      15.00       75.00            
3             steve     01/21/13    01/27/2013   False      10.00       50.00
```

Comment: In addition to Mr. Fuzzy Button's question: which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: Two questions - (1) What is your DB? SQL Server? MySQL? Or do you want this via Linq? and (2) What have you tried? What is your current SQL that's not working??

Comment: I'm using MS-Access 2007, VS 2008 frontend

Comment: SELECT        e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, MIN(et.start_date) AS minofstart_date, et.Paid, et.Hours_Worked
FROM            (Employees_Master e INNER JOIN
                         Employee_Trasaction et ON e.EmployeeID = et.Employee_ID)
WHERE        (et.Paid = False)
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, et.Paid, et.Hours_Worked  this query display all unpaid dates

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't not mention the RDBMS you are using, the query below works almost on all RDBMS (*not all*)

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN Emp_transaction b
            ON a.Emp_ID = b.Emp_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Emp_ID, MIN(start_DATE) min_date
            FROM    emp_transaction
            WHERE   Paid_Status = 'False'
            GROUP   BY Emp_ID
        ) c ON b.Emp_ID = c.Emp_ID AND
                b.start_date = c.min_DATE
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4df00/1)

But if your RDBMS Supports `Window Functions`,

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.TransID, b.start_Date, b.End_date, 
        b.Paid_status, b.Total_Hours, b.Total_Pay
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  TransID, Emp_ID, start_Date, End_date, Paid_status, Total_Hours, Total_Pay,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_ID ORDER BY start_Date ASC) rn
            FROM    emp_transaction
            WHERE   Paid_status = 'False'
        ) b ON a.Emp_ID = b.Emp_ID AND
                b.rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2a8a4/3)

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...